# Need to Revise version of SQL Server generated XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, tags, for-xml-path

The following lines of code generate me an XML file looking like the below set, which is almost acceptable to my client.  I say ALMOST because the one change I need to to have `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` versus the standard `<?xml version="1.0">` which is at the top of every XML file I generate using the EXEC xp_cmdshell command below.  I essentially need `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` instead of `<?xml version="1.0">`.  Can someone please tell me how this can be accomplished?

```
-- SQL CODE USED TO GENERATE XML FILE - Using XML Path
    SET @FileString = @FileName + '.xml" -S ALSCG-JPATHIL\SQLEXPRESS -T -c -t,'
    SET @SQLSTRING = 'bcp ";WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT ''urn:CP-xml'') select A.TargetSystem AS ''Header/Target'' from [Header] A FOR XML PATH(''Qty'')" queryout "C:\Program Files\'
    SET @SQLSTRING = @SQLSTRING + @FileString
    EXEC xp_cmdshell @SQLSTRING



 -- XML FILE CONTENTS GENERATED  - Missing the Encoding Condition here
    <?xml version="1.0">
    <Qty xmlns="urn:CP-xml">
    <Header>
    <Target></Target>
    </Header>
    </Qty>




 -- XML FILE CONTENTS DESIRED - Note only difference is the Encoding!
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Qty xmlns="urn:CP-xml">
    <Header>
    <Target></Target>
    </Header>
    </Qty>
```

Answer (score 0):

The very last response in [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3d899443-a1ea-403d-9e2e-68b593875d23/preserve-utf8-encoding-in-sql-server-when-converting-to-xml-datatype?forum=transactsql) has the only "solution" to this problem that I've been able to find

> Hi, (late response but might help someone in future) VARBINARY did not
>   work for me, probably 'coz of the my datasource didn't comply. Heres
>   what worked for me at the SQL end;
>
> 1) Store your raw xml data as VARCHAR or TEXT (instead of NVARCHAR or
>   NTEXT) into a variable,
>
> 2) Read this variable into the xml data type using utf-8 encoding.
>   Something like:
>
> ```
> DECLARE @TempHTMLText
>
> SET @TempHTMLText = --your raw xml data DECLARE @XMLDataText XML
>
> SELECT @XMLDataType = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>' + @TempHTMLText
> ```

I don't think you'd need to do exactly that, rather use the following query:

```
DECLARE @Xml XML;

WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'urn:CP-xml') 
SELECT @Xml = (select A.TargetSystem AS 'Header/Target' from [Header] A FOR XML PATH('Qty'));

SELECT CONCAT('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>', CAST(@Xml AS VARCHAR(MAX)))
```

Note that in my testing, I was unable to convert this data back to XML while preserving the encoding tag. That seems to be enforced explicitly by the XML data type